# Why did the subProcess forked by the main process of Electron v20 exit immediately with code 134

Tags: windows, electron, fork, child-process, exit-code

I have an Electron application, recently upgraded to version 20, some windows users have encountered a problem, check the log because a child process cannot be created normally。

this is log describing:

```txt
2023/7/13 12:39:31.122[warn][CHILD] child path:C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\TT\resources\app.asar\dist\electron\child.js
2023/7/13 12:39:31.136[warn][CHILD] pid:3820, connect:true
2023/7/13 12:39:31.136[info][CHILD] spawn
2023/7/13 12:39:31.217[info][CHILD] disconnect
2023/7/13 12:39:31.220[info][CHILD] exit code:134  sign:null
2023/7/13 12:39:31.220[info][CHILD] close
```

this is the code:

```js
this._process = cp.fork(childPath, args, options)

this._process.on('disconnect', () => {
    log.info('[CHILD] disconnect')
})

this._process.on('close', () => {
    log.info('[CHILD] close')
})

this._process.on('spawn', () => {
    log.info('[CHILD] spawn')
})

this._process.on('exit', (code, sign) => {
    log.info(`[CHILD] exit code:${code}  sign:${sign}`)
})

log.warn('[CHILD] pid:' + this._process.pid + `, connect:${this._process.connected}`)
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

On the computer that encountered this problem, I tried set the child.js file empty or just a few lines codes. The problem is still there and the difference is that the exit code alter to code 7